# Grails 4: @GrailsCompileStatic annotation not working

Tags: grails, grails-4

**Migration from grails 3.3.5 -> grails 4.0.0.M2**

My class has been annotated with `@GrailsCompileStatic` & it used to compile without any issues in 3.3.5.

Many other classes are also showing errors for methods which are additionally provided by groovy such as `Date.parse()` or `Date.format()` or `Date.minus()`

**Error:**

```
FileCommandReader.groovy: 163: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.util.Date#parse(java.lang.String, java.lang.String). Please check if the declared type is correct and if the method exists.
 @ line 163, column 17.
                Date expiry = Date.parse("HH:mm:ss", cols[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a `@GrailsCompileStatic` issue.  Grails 4.0 uses Groovy 2.5.6.  The following code will not compile with Groovy 2.5.6...

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Helper {

    void someMethod() {
        Date.parse '', ''
    }
}
```

Grails 3.3.5 uses Groovy 2.4.15 and the code above is valid in Groovy 2.4.15.

Comment: The groovy-dateutil methods are an optional module in Groovy 2.5 making way for the now recommended groovy-datetime module (java.time package). You need to add the extra groovy-dateutil dependency if you want to use those extension methods.

Comment: Thanks @PaulKing will use alternate options.